# Error while calling a function using "onOpen(e)"

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run a function when a google sheet is opened for which i am trying to call a function using function onOpen(e)

but I get error when i try to debug

Missing { before function body. (line 8, file "Code") (row where function UpdateColData is called)

here is my code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Scripts')
  .addItem('test', 'Test1')
  .addToUi();


function UpdateColData();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a { on line 8 or you did not intend to write the second one 
`function UpdateColData();` or `function UpdateColData(){}`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line `function UpdateColData();`. The syntax error is saying that you did not open the function definition with a "{" like so:

```
function UpdateColData() {
}
```

What you supplied was invalid javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Scripts')
  .addItem('test', 'Test1')
  .addToUi();
  UpdateColData();

  }

function UpdateColData() {
  //function definition
}
```

> Assuming that you are doing nothing that requires authorization in UpdateColData() then this should work.  Although it sounds like you're updating data so my guess is that this won't work because simple triggers cannot perform actions that require authorization.  You will have to use an installable trigger

- [Simple Trigger Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)

Comment: sorry but i did not get your comment. i have a UpdateColData function that deletes some rows and some unwanted columns (based on date)  which runs by itself. I want to run this code moment i open the google sheet.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to make it [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: this worked. Thanks alot.  ````function UpdateColData(){}

Comment: Please select an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call a function by using the word function:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Scripts')
  .addItem('test', 'Test1')
  .addToUi();

   UpdateColData();

  }
```